How can I make a shortcut in Shortcuts.app on a Mac/iPhone continue the rest of the flow even if one task failed?
I'm working on a shortcut using the Mac/iPhone Shortcut app, and I need some help. My shortcut consists of multiple tasks, but I've run into an issue. If one of the tasks fails, the entire shortcut stops executing.
Is there a way to make the shortcut continue running the remaining tasks even if one of them fails? Any tips or detailed steps on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.
Here's my shortcut link to the Runs Shell Script task that fails.

You are already performing some comparisons on the result, what kind of error handling is in the shell script?

There isn't basically. It just runs a remote script (osascript) to connect to a VPN and sometimes it fails. So the return result sometimes contain something similar to this
/Applications/ConnectToVPN.scpt: execution error: Can not click UI Element "Connect" of group 1 of window "Forcepoint NGFW VPN Client" of application process "Forcepoint NGFW VPN Client" (-2700)
Also - the variable is never populated too.

The error is not trapped, so the action fails - you would need to do something like use a try statement in the osascript and return missing value on error.

I couldn't any action in the apple's shortcut actions' list like try, do you know of any?

You are running an AppleScript via osascript - that script is what you would need to modify.
